# goal is validate the response sent by different apis is valid, which is request in my api. question is how to validate json against RAML Datatype?

Tags: json, mulesoft

My overall goal is to validate the response sent by different APIs and forwarded response as request to my API.

and using a discriminator to identify TYPE of object, validate against its raml data type.

Have doubt in How to validate JSON against RAML Datatype?

I found some info on parsing RAML datatype, in last comment here, https://help.mulesoft.com/s/question/0D52T00004mXXa4SAG/how-to-validate-json-object-using-a-raml-datatype

If can explain last comment in detail or some other alternative.

Attaching both RAML file using discriminator and flow.

```yaml
#%RAML 1.0 Fragment
version: v1
title: My API With Types
types:
 Person:
  type: object
  discriminator: kind
  properties:
   name: string
   kind: string
 Employee:
  type: Person
  discriminatorValue: employee # override default
  properties:
   employeeId: number
 User:
  type: Person
  discriminatorValue: user # override default
  properties:
   userId: string
 /schema-val:
 post:
   #description: Retrieve a list of all the users
  body:
   application/json:
    type: Person
  responses:
   200:
    body:
    description: http status and message OK
    text/html: success      
   400:
    body:
    description: error message
    text/html: error
```

Flow xml-

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule
    xmlns:ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core"
    xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
    xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
    xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core/current/mule-ee.xsd">
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_config" doc:name="HTTP Listener config" doc:id="4f571302-95d5-4f0c-a320-e78b01823709" >
        <http:listener-connection host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" />
    </http:listener-config>
    <flow name="responsevalidationFlow" doc:id="88c44a1d-eff1-4f9d-b688-6933579553da" >
        <http:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="c8826a0f-fa70-4714-a751-2eb5a54d2f09" allowedMethods="POST" path="/schema-val" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config"/>
        <set-payload value="#payload" doc:name="Set Payload" doc:id="794b25c3-301b-4082-a309-72adcc7ed25f" />
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="62cac08d-3fd2-491d-bbfd-2a1888635b87" message="#payload"/>
        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="83d88fcc-657b-42f6-987f-87578728abf2" >
            <ee:message >
                <ee:set-payload >
                    <![CDATA[%dw 2.0

output application/java
---
{
  name: payload.name,
  kind: payload.kind,
  employeeId: payload.employeeId,
  userId: payload.userId
}]]>
                </ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="69fb1f31-6fc1-4904-bbb4-9c0f9cf35722" message="#payload"/>
        <set-variable value="#payload.kind" doc:name="Set Variable" doc:id="9958d86f-cd2e-4e9f-aa5c-a6efab3ed8ae" variableName="kind"/>
        <choice doc:name="Choice" doc:id="b186199b-0a0a-41ad-8353-d377054a9e33" >
            <when expression="#vars.kind=='employee'">
                <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="e75961d3-001c-421e-aaf4-1f04dd6a01a1" message='"in employee"'/>
            </when>
            <when expression="#vars.kind=='user'">
                <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="23ce14a9-94c1-4af3-b047-607dda35ce36" message='"in user"'/>
            </when>
            <otherwise >
                <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="aa5471ed-5944-4c72-8628-93b83cc0e31d" message='"in default"'/>
            </otherwise>
        </choice>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Expected Output

When I hit `http://localhost:8081/schema-val` with below payloads

`{ "name": "fred", "kind": "employee", "employeeId": "e123" }`

`{ "name": "barney", "kind": "user", "userId": "u999" }`

Then the flow should throw error if employeeId is not a number maybe, that is invalid request.

Comment: Why don't you send the request to your API and that API will automatically validate the requests (via APKit) if you have defined the REST API specs?

Comment: Why not just use APIKit which performs the validation automatically? What do you mean by discriminator type?

Answer (score 0):

Use the APIKit router. Studio can autogenerate the needed flows automatically from a RAML specification of the API. That RAML should reference your data type RAML. Validation is automatic.

Answer (score -2):

APIKIT Router not validating discriminator RAML.Every request getting passed.

RAML

#%RAML 1.0

version: v1

```yaml
title: My API With Types

types:

 Person:

  type: object

  discriminator: kind

  properties:

   name: string

   kind: string

 Employee:

  type: Person

  discriminatorValue: employee # override default

  properties:

   employeeId:

    required: true

    minLength: 3

    type: string

    

 User:

  type: Person

  discriminatorValue: user # override default

  properties:

   userId: string
```

/schema-val:

```yaml
 post:

   #description: Retrieve a list of all the users  

  body:

   application/json:

    type: Person

  responses:

   200:

    body:

     application/text: 

      example: success     

   400:

    body:

     application/text: 

      example: error
```

Flow-

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 

<mule xmlns:apikit="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/mule-apikit" xmlns:ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core"

xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"

xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd

http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd

http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core/current/mule-ee.xsd

http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/mule-apikit http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/mule-apikit/current/mule-apikit.xsd">

<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_config" doc:name="HTTP Listener config" doc:id="4f571302-95d5-4f0c-a320-e78b01823709" >

<http:listener-connection host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" />

</http:listener-config>

<apikit:config outboundHeadersMapName="outboundHeadersMapName" httpStatusVarName="httpStatus" doc:name="Router" doc:id="03538ab3-9515-4a48-8b60-58f44d528072" name="Router1" api="api\discriminatorValue.raml" raml="api\discriminatorValue.raml" keepRamlBaseUri="true">

<apikit:flow-mappings >

<apikit:flow-mapping resource="/schema-val" action="post" content-type="application/json" flow-ref="responsevalidationFlow1" />

</apikit:flow-mappings>

</apikit:config>

<flow name="responsevalidationFlow" doc:id="88c44a1d-eff1-4f9d-b688-6933579553da" >

<http:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="c8826a0f-fa70-4714-a751-2eb5a54d2f09" allowedMethods="POST" path="/schema-val" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config"/>

<set-payload value="#payload" doc:name="Set Payload" doc:id="794b25c3-301b-4082-a309-72adcc7ed25f" />

<apikit:router doc:name="APIkit Router" doc:id="ccf175a8-5ed1-441d-850a-ef94eb9d7af5" config-ref="Router1" />

<logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="62cac08d-3fd2-491d-bbfd-2a1888635b87" message="#payload"/>

<logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="69fb1f31-6fc1-4904-bbb4-9c0f9cf35722" message="#payload"/>

<set-variable value="#payload.kind" doc:name="Set Variable" doc:id="9958d86f-cd2e-4e9f-aa5c-a6efab3ed8ae" variableName="kind"/>

<choice doc:name="Choice" doc:id="b186199b-0a0a-41ad-8353-d377054a9e33" >

<when expression="#vars.kind=='employee'">

<logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="e75961d3-001c-421e-aaf4-1f04dd6a01a1" message='"in employee"'/>

</when>

<when expression="#vars.kind=='user'">

<logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="23ce14a9-94c1-4af3-b047-607dda35ce36" message='"in user"'/>

</when>

<otherwise >

<logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="aa5471ed-5944-4c72-8628-93b83cc0e31d" message='"in default"'/>

</otherwise>

</choice>

</flow>

<flow name="responsevalidationFlow1" doc:id="0119d024-14b3-4aed-88ca-a1213726cb23" >

<logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="ed02255f-9461-4703-b027-325c71342c49" message='#vars.httpStatus'/>

</flow>

</mule>
```

#%RAML 1.0

version: v1

```yaml
title: My API With Types

types:

 Person:

  type: object

  discriminator: kind

  properties:

   name: string

   kind: string

 Employee:

  type: Person

  discriminatorValue: employee # override default

  properties:

   employeeId:

    required: true

    minLength: 3

    type: string

    

 User:

  type: Person

  discriminatorValue: user # override default

  properties:

   userId: string
```

/schema-val:

```yaml
 post:

   #description: Retrieve a list of all the users  

  body:

   application/json:

    type: Employee

  responses:

   200:

    body:

     application/text: 

      example: success     

   400:

    body:

     application/text: 

      example: error
```

If change type to "Employee" in RAML it works like in above RAML.But we want generic.

```json
{ "name": "fred", "kind": "employee", "employeeId": "e1" }
```

/employeeId expected minLength: 3, actual: 2